# Ubuntu 11.04: No Audio Output

Tags: audio, ubuntu-11.04

I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 11.04 earlier this week and I'm having trouble getting my audio online.  It was working fine in 10.04 and all the resources I can find on troubleshooting seem to be fairly dated so I'm not sure if they apply.

```
CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]
Analog Stereo Duplex
```

Playing a WMA file shows 0.00db output when I mouse over the sound controller in the status bar.  Obviously, no output from my speakers.

I tried adjusting the profile, thinking I might have the wrong one.  That seems to have made things worse.  Where mouse over originally said something along the lines of "Oxygen HD Audio," it now reads "Dummy Output."  Selecting "Test Speakers" in sound preferences crashes the dialog.

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot the previous ubuntu (live cd) which detected your card correctly and use `lsmod` to figure out which sound module it loaded. Load the same kernel module (`modprobe`) in the new version. If that does not do the trick, then something has changed in the way ubuntu configures sound devices. That means you'll have to look through the docs.

For reference: [Ubuntu community: Sound](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sound)